# Create empty object in JSON via Json4s DSL

Tags: scala, json4s

The JSON documents I'm creating need to have a `properties` field, even if there are no properties.

`{"foo":"bar","properties":{}}` is legal, `{"foo":"bar"}` is illegal.

How can I define an empty object to use as the properties value using the Json4s DSL?

```
("foo" -> "bar") ~ ("properties" -> ???)
```

I have tried `Map.empty`, `new Object`, `()`. All of these are not the correct type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used Json4s, but it seemed to work with:

```
val map = ("foo" -> "bar") ~ ("properties" -> Nil)
```

Here is my full code:

```
  import org.json4s._
  import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
  import org.json4s.JsonDSL._

  val map = ("foo" -> "bar") ~ ("properties" -> Nil)

  println(compact(render(map)))
```